# Adding a small image in a list?

Tags: html, css

I have made a dropdown menu. I need a 25px x 25px image to the left of the dropdown list's text? Every time i try, the image will not appear? Why? and how do i fix it? I have tried and tried, but the image will never appear. http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/M4Ef2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```css
.custom-select ul {
  ...
  background: url("myimage.png") left top no-repeat;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I need a different picture per <li> and i need it inside of it. I need to add it to the html Style="..."

Comment: If you apply the style to ``.custom-select li`` the image will be applied to every list item

Answer (score 1):

<del>I don't think you can put an image tag in a option tag, the best thing would be to set a background image and padding on the option tag.</del>
If you look at the script you'll see that it rebuilds the `.custom-select ul` that's why you lose any `<img>` in the markup, check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Ef2/2/) where I comment out that code.

```
$('#test_select option').each(function(i){
    html.push('<li rel="'+$(this).val() +'">'+$(this).text()+'</li>');
});

$('.custom-select ul').html(html.join(''))
```

Comment: When ever i add the image through Chrome development tools...it works, but when i add it in the code, it does not...

Comment: @EliteGamer If you look at the script you'll see that it rebuilds the `.custom-select ul` that's why you lose any `<img>` in the markup, check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Ef2/2/) where I comment out that code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing someting, I am not sure why people are suggesting stuff with `<li>`. If you want the 25x25 image to appear in the drop down, use:

**CSS**

```
select#test_select option[value="graphic designer"] {
 background: url("myimage.png") left top no-repeat;
 padding-left: 50px;  
} // continue with every value
```